# texshade: how to change fontshape?

Tags: fonts

I tried to use the following codes to change the fontshape of the output of `texshade` package as  times NEW roman, however, it seemed nothing had changed without any warnings, why?

And interestingly, when i tried to use the following codes to export a pdf file but without using the `texshade` package, it seemed the fontshape in the output changed as times NEW roman!!!why???

This is the codes i used:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just to generate dummy text

\usepackage{texshade}

\begin{document}

\begin{texshade}{all_OXA_mafft.fasta}

\shadingmode{diverse}

\allmatchresidues{Black}{White}{upper}{up}

\conservedresidues{Black}{White}{upper}{up}

\similarresidues{Black}{White}{upper}{up}

\nomatchresidues{Black}{White}{upper}{up}

\showruler{top}{1}

\shownumbering{left}

\shownames{left}

\residuesperline*{80}

\hideconsensus

\rulerlarge

\end{texshade}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. No one has the fasta file so your minimal example is incomplete and one can only guess. Try putting \rmfamily immediately after the \begin{texshade} line.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it could not work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE. Setting the font of formatted sequence data can be achieved using either the `\setfont` command, or one or more of: `\setfamily`, `\setseries`, `\setshape` and `\setsize`, depending on the font characteristic to be set. The use of these commands is described in section 4.9.1 of the `TeXShade` manual v1.25 p41.

The following MWE illustrates the use of `\setfont` using a fasta data file copied from the `TeXShade manual`.

```
% Example data file from TeXShade manual v1.25 p41
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.fasta}
>AQP1.PRO
MAS........................EIKKKLFWRAVVAEFLAMTLFVFISIGSALGFNYPLERNQTLVQDNVKVSLAFGLSIATL
>AQP2.PRO
MW.........................ELRSIAFSRAVLAEFLATLLFVFFGLGSALQWA...SS....PPSVLQIAVAFGLGIGIL
>AQP3.PRO
M.........NRCG.....EMLHIRYR......LLRQALAECLGTLILVMFGCGSVAQVVLSRGTHGGF....LTINLAFGFAVTLA
>AQP4.PRO
MSDGAAARRWGKCGPPCSRESIMVAFKGVWTQAFWKAVTAEFLAMLIFVLLSVGSTINWG...GSENPLPVDMVLISLCFGLSIATM
>AQP5.PRO
MK........................KEVCSLAFFKAVFAEFLATLIFVFFGLGSALKWP...SA....LPTILQISIAFGLAIGTL
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just to generate dummy text
\usepackage{texshade}
\begin{document}
\begin{texshade}{mydata.fasta}
% \setfont{text}   %The name of the element to apply the font to:
%                   = numbering, names, residues, features,featurestyles, hideblock, ruler, and legend.
%         {family} %The font family = rm, sf, tt
%         {series} %Bold (bd) or normal (md)
%         {shape}  %The font shape = it, sl, sc, up
%         {size}   %The known TeX sizes e.g. tiny, scriptsize, small, large, huge
\setfont{ruler}{rm}{md}{up}{tiny}
\setfont{numbering}{rm}{md}{up}{scriptsize}
\setfont{names}{rm}{md}{up}{scriptsize}
\setfont{residues}{rm}{md}{up}{scriptsize}
% Not in use with this data set 
%\setfont{features}{rm}{md}{up}{scriptsize}
%\setfont{featurestyles}{rm}{md}{up}{scriptsize}
%\setfont{hideblock}{rm}{md}{up}{scriptsize}
%\setfont{legend}{rm}{md}{up}{scriptsize}
\shadingmode{diverse}
\allmatchresidues{Black}{White}{upper}{up}
\conservedresidues{Black}{White}{upper}{up}
\similarresidues{Black}{White}{upper}{up}
\nomatchresidues{Black}{White}{upper}{up}
\showruler{top}{1}
\rulersteps{1}
\shownumbering{left}
\shownames{left}
\residuesperline*{40}
%\hideconsensus
%\rulerlarge % overrides font setting above for the ruler
\end{texshade}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Note that the following warning is generated. Someone knowledgeable about such warning messages may be able to explain what is happening.

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'T1/rm/m/n' undefined (Font)
>   using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 62.
>
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd")
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd") . . ) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf4IZ.png)
>   (Ex138-1a.aux)
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults
>   substituted.

The fonts embedded in the PDF file are:
[image]